# The use of 'get rid of'

Tags: active-vs-passive

During a discussion, a question occurred to me. If we want to get rid of something **that is done to us**, should we use Active voice or passive voice? Example: I have a fellow who talks too much. I am annoyed and want no more of his talking. Which one of the following two should I use?

---

I want to get rid of talking.

---

I want to get rid of being talked to.

Comment: I want to get rid of being to be talked with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of **active voice** or **passive voice**, just use them correctly.

**Active voice**

> I want to get rid of **his / their / ...** talking.

It implies that ONLY the talking is annoying.

> I want to get rid of **him / them / ...** talking.

It implies that you *might* want to get rid of the people also, not only the talking.

**Passive voice**

> I want to get rid of being talked to.

(It is correct already in your question)

---

However, I would recommend the use of **to avoid** instead of **to get rid of**.

> I want **to avoid** him talking.

"To get rid of" implies that the object is physical, while that talking cannot be seen / touched.

> It's time to get rid of this **old sweater**.

or:

> She finally got rid of **him**.

See [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20rid%20of)

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of someone if you don’t want the person to be with you and thus to talk to you any longer.

> We finally got rid of my little sister by telling her scary stories.
>   He annoyed me. I wanted to get rid of him.

Your 1st sentence looks obscure. Don't you want to talk at all? Your 2nd sentence doesn't sound right to me.